# Getting outdoor only panoramas from Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-street-view, panoramas

I am using this code to get Panorama near coordinates:

```
self.panoramaView = [[GMSPanoramaView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.view = self.panoramaView;

[self.panoramaView moveNearCoordinate:self.coordinate];

GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:self.coordinate];
marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PlacePin"];
marker.panoramaView = self.panoramaView;
```

I found that in [Google API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewSource) there is `source` parameter with possible `Outdoor` value for getting only outdoor panoramas. Is it possible for iOS SDK? I can't find any paramater like this in documentation but I am not sure. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is only available in JavaScript API. No IOS or Android.

**UPDATE:**

**As of February 6, 2018 this feature is available on iOS.**

> Maps SDK for iOS Version 2.6.0 - February 6, 2018
>
> Added a Source attribute to Panorama searches allowing them to be restricted to outdoor-only
>   results. Note that this feature is experimental and some searches may
>   still include indoor panoramas.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases